# Align DIV bottom of the next page in pdf file

Tags: apex, visualforce, css

I created pdf file using visualforce renderAs. In visualforce I have a table tr in **apex:repeat** and below that table one DIV tag. This div tag appears at bottom of the page when there is content only in single page. But when content going out of first page(content in td) I want DIV tag at bottom of second page only not for first page. I have following code:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" renderAs="pdf" applyhtmltag="false" applyBodyTag="false" standardController="Opportunity" extensions="Invoice_PDF_Controller" action="{!doDmlht}">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
    @page {
        border: 2px solid black;

        @top-center {
            content: element(header);
        }

        @bottom-left {
            content: element(footer);
        }
    }

    div.header {
        padding: 10px;
        /*margin-top: 50px*/
        position: running(header);
    }

    div.footer {
        display: block;
        padding: 0px;
        position: running(footer);
    }

    .pagenumber:before {
        content: counter(page);
    }

    .pagecount:before {
        content: counter(pages);
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <apex:repeat>
                <tr>
                    <td>some content..</td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </table>
        <div style="position: fixed;bottom: 0;">
            some content..
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I used `style="position: fixed;bottom: 0;"` for last div but it also appears for first page. I tried many ways but not use.

Comment: try using HTML <footer> and let me know if it works.

Comment: Hey MIX! thanks for reply. when i use <footer> it appers at top of the second page not to bottom.  i want  it to locate at bottom.

Comment: I  did it by adding <footer style="position:absolute; top:1790px;"> but it will fail if content in td have in  second page upto bottom then footer will appear at top of the third page.Please provide ultimate solution for it.

Comment: I think only way solve this issue is to create sticky footer. Please refer below link : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_fixed_footer

Comment: I tried that too but it added footer also for first page.I want to add footer only for  bottom of the last page.

Comment: You need to write some javascript code, get the last page and put this sticky footer dynamically.